# One category not displaying template updates

Tags: categories, templates, updates

I've tried refreshing, clearing the cache, opening in a new browser, renaming it from index to category.php-- ALL but one category display the correct template. I'm beyond stumped.

One clue is that if I omit the loop from the template, the sidebar shows up. Otherwise it gets the 'cached' or previous version of that template page.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that some wacky code was inserted by either the Wordpress content editor or the author who added it to the post, which I highly doubt. It was some commented out randomness, that while being a part of the post itself, broke the whole page.

Hopefully this ridiculous problem/solution is found to be helpful by someone else. Oh. Lee. Chit. This was a pain in the ess.

Wanna see it? Starts after the date:

```
<p><em>Tuesday, August 13th, 2013</em></p>
    <p><!--<br />
P { margin-bottom: 0.08in; }<br />
&#8211;</p>
<p style="text-align: left"><a href="http://www....
```